# ¿Es posible crear una tabla en Angular DataTables con un factory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

Estoy usando el famoso plugin [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) que combina Jquery Datatables con Angular.

Recién aprendí cómo utilizar un factory para traerse datos de un archivo JSON.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Podría utilizar un factory en angular-datatables para utilizarlo como *source*?

**EDITADO (22/06/2016)**

Esto es lo que he intentado:

1. Un factory global que rescate la data de un JSON con muchas URL

```js
//Factory que traerá la data Global
statisticsModule.factory('globalFactory', function($rootScope, $http){

  var globalFactory = {};

  globalFactory.getUrl = function(){
    return $http.get('../statistics/php/config_statistics.json');
  };

  return globalFactory;

});
```

2. Un controlador que utilice ese factory, busque la URL específica que quiero  y la utiliza como *source* en el *datatable*:

```js
//Controller / Controlador
statisticsModule.controller("dataController", dataController); //Fin controlador

  function dataController($scope, $http, globalFactory, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder){
    //Promise con el factory
    globalFactory.getUrl().then(function(response){

      //Obtener data
      var urlGlobal = response.data;
      //Filtrar data. arrayReportBD : Arreglo con las URL de los reportes
      var deserialize = angular.fromJson(urlGlobal.config.graph_conf_array.arrayReportBD);
      //Data Distribución de Estatus
      var urlStatus = deserialize[0];

      //Obtener data de Distribución de Estatus
      $http.get(urlStatus).success(function(data){

      console.log(data);

      var vm = this;
      vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(data)
      .withDOM('lfrtip')
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      .withLanguage({
        "sEmptyTable":     "No hay datos para cargar en la tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando _START_ de _END_ de _TOTAL_ entradas",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando 0 de 0 de 0 entradas",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtradas _MAX_ entradas totales)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ entradas",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primera",
            "sLast":     "Última",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
          },
          "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": activar para ordenar de forma ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": activar para ordenar de forma descendente"
          }
        });
        vm.dtColumns = [
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('gob_code').withTitle('Cód. Gob.'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('fci_code').withTitle('Cód. FCI'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('NOMBRE'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('status').withTitle('ESTATUS')
        ];

      }).error(function(err){

      });//Fin $http

    });//Fin promise

  }//Fin función
```

3. Esta es la parte de mi vista que corresponde al datatable:

```html
<div ng-controller="dataController as showCase">
  <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table>
</div>
```

**POST-DATA (EDITADA)**
Si preguntan:

1. Me trae la data correctamente, lo que no puedo es usarla en el *datatable*

Comment: La respuesta es si lo puedes hacer.

Comment: ¿Pero cómo lo hago?

Comment: Hola @Ulises. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, la respuesta es básicamente "sí, se puede" o "no, no se puede". Te recomiendo redactar la pregunta de manera que preguntes "cómo" lograrlo, que te provean algún ejemplo. Si puedes, mostrar lo que has intentado para ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****RESUELTA (23/06/2016)****

La pude resolver, aquí en otro post de StackOverflow en inglés publiqué la respuesta:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993845/6291719